# HHVM fastcgi gives status code "500 OK" w

Tags: php, codeigniter, hhvm

I'm running HHVM as a PHP-FPM replacement with Nginx, my pages are returning content just fine, but the status code is always "500 OK" eventhough I can't find any errors anywhere!

All of this is using the example configs from the HHVM setup guide and the latest stable from the HHVM ppa.
The PHP Application is based on the CodeIgniter framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter supresses warnings when making a database connection by prefixing the connect with an @ like; `@mysqli_connect`

In HHVM this error is still registered as an error but it won't halt on it and just continues and it changes the status code to `500 OK`

Comment: Is there a bug in HHVM? If so, please open an issue on github.

Comment: hmm, I hadn't noticed that and I think the 'bug' is that when an error is silenced/supresses that it sets the status code to `500 OK`

I kinda wrote this Q&A for other people running into `500 OK` so that they would know they should be looking for a silenced/supressed error.